# Copy divs with certain id's to targets with related id's

Tags: javascript, copy, handlebars.js

How do I copy the content from all divs with a certain class or a certain beginning of an id to a bunch of divs with related id's? The examples I found didn't go through multiple copies. I have a solution that is working ok but instead of calling each copy with the id I would like to make the logic better.

Here's what I have now.

HTML (handlebars template)

```
<!-- the id comes from handlebar content. There are many like this -->

<pre><code id="target-example-01" class='language-markup'></code></pre>

<!-- this content is put to place once handlebars has rendered the page  -->
<div id="code-examples" style="display: none;">
  <div class='code-example' id="source-example-01">
    this is my a code example... there are many like me...
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript

```
var source = document.getElementById('source-example-01').innerHTML;
var target = document.getElementById('target-example-01');
if (target) target.innerHTML=source;
```

This works ok but I have 100 examples so I wouldn't like to have 300 lines of code to manually maintain just to copy the content. How do I go through all the divs with "code-example" class and copy their content to divs with a matching id. All the source divs will have the id="source-(example-identifier)" and all the target divs will have the id="target-(example-identifier)". I guess the class wouldn't be needed if the code would go through all items with the id beginning with "source-"

Comment: This is how I solved it. I gave the <code> elements another class "target-example" and then simply went through all of them in the js and populated them with item smatching a similar id with "source-" prefix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How do I go through all the divs with "code-example" class and copy
>   their content to divs with a matching id

Assuming that index of `code-example` elements is same as that of targets, then try

```
var allCodeExamples = document.getElementsByClassName( "code-example" );
for ( var counter = 0; counter < allCodeExamples.length ; counter++ )
{
   var index = ("0" + counter).slice( -2 );
   var target = document.getElementById( "target-example-" + index );
   target.innerHTML = allCodeExamples[counter].innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: I believe this solves the original question. I actually realised that it makes more sense to see which examples are on the page and then populating them. I'll accept your answer and add my own example.

Answer (score 1):

I would be old school and stick with using `getElementsByClassName()` but since the question is how to target divs will have the id="target-(example-identifier) you can use `querySelectorAll()`

```
document.querySelectorAll('div[id^="source-example-"]')
```

for more information about **[querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**

> Returns a list of the elements within the document (using depth-first pre-order traversal of the document's nodes) that match the specified group of selectors. The object returned is a NodeList.

So the output is very much like using `getElementsByClassName()`

If you have any questions please leave a comment below and I will reply as soon as possible.

> How to target a specific tag with a class and id?

```
document.querySelectorAll('div.code-example[id^="source-example-"]')
```

You will still need to loop through the contend just like you would for returning elements by class name but this query selector will only return div elements with the class name `code-example` and contains `source-example-` in the `id` attribute.

```js
function QuerySelector() {
var Selector=document.querySelectorAll('div.code-example[id^="source-example-"]');
for(var i=0; i<Selector.length; i++){
alert(Selector[i].innerHTML);
}
}
```

```html
<div class="code-example" id="source-example-01">Content Line One. - with class and id </div>
<div class="code-example">Content Line Two. - with correct class but no ID</div>
<div class="code-example" id="source-example-02">Content Line Three. - with class and id </div>
<button onclick="QuerySelector()">Get</button>
```

I hope this helps. Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of data attributes for this using jquery:

```
<!-- the id comes from handlebar content. There are many like this -->

<pre><code id="target-example-01" class='language-markup'></code></pre>

<!-- this content is put to place once handlebars has rendered the page  -->
<div id="code-examples" style="display: none;">
  <div class='code-example' id="source-example-01" data-target="#target-example-01">
    this is my a code example... there are many like me...
  </div>
</div>

$(function(){
   var targetId;

   $(".code-example").each(function(){
      targetId = $(this).attr("data-target");
      $(targetId).html($(this).html());
   });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I realised it makes more sense to check which examples are on the page and fetch the content for their source id's. I added another class to the code-tags "target-example"

Here's the javascript (jquery would probably make it nicer looking)

```
var examples = document.getElementsByClassName('target-example');
var i;
var id;
for (i = 0; i < examples.length; i++) {
    id = examples[i].id;
    var source = document.getElementById('source-'+id).innerHTML;
    if (source) examples[i].innerHTML=source;
}
```